# what layout is used to draw a monopoly-like game board

Tags: android, gridview, tablelayout

Im trying to draw a game map in an android app similar to the game board of monopoly where all the squares are all on the edges.

At first I wanted to use GridView because its basically gonna be a series of boxes containing images that can be clicked. However, I found out that gridview does not support spanning. I need the center part of the game board to be "merged".

Now, i'm trying to use tablelayout. The board has a fixed number of columns and rows. With table layout, I have to specify the width and height of the objects. But specifying a fixed width and height might not work in all different screen sizes.

What can you suggest as the best approach in drawing a board similar to monopoly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need onclick listeners on each square on the board and Im not sure how complicated it is to implement it on a canvas.

So I just settled with using nested LinearLayout. The weight attribute made it easy to give the child views within the layout equal width/height.

Answer (score 1):

I think Table Layout is probably going to be your best bet.  Here's a good tutorial, in case you haven't come across it yet: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Since this is a game though, you might consider researching and reading up on Canvas and OpenGL, or even Android NDK.  Working in these topics may be a steeper learning curve, but the results will be far greater than with just using simple layouts.

Once you cross the line from regular apps to gaming apps, you really need to work with the game development technologies.

Good luck!

db

Comment: Do most games use canvas than the other native android ui elements? I did a maze game once using canvas. But i thought since it's just a simple 2d board, using standard view elements would be better. OpenGL, I think, would be appropriate if I wanted to create a 3d version.